# Cache instagram API request

Tags: php, json, api, caching, laravel

I am implementing some photos from instagram to use in my footer as decoration in my laravel project. But when I refresh the page it does the api call over and over again. I was thinking of caching or storing the call in a session so I don't always have to send an API request... So how can I cache this api request?

PHP:

```
<?php
$clientid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/kittens/media/recent?client_id=".$clientid;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$results = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
?>
```

HTML:

```
<footer>
<?php
    echo "<ul class='inline-list'>";    
    foreach ($results->data as $result) {
        echo "<li><img src='".$result->images->thumbnail->url."'></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
</footer>
```

Comment: So what's your question about? How to cache?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how I can cache this api request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cache request you can write it into a file and check modification date or use some kind of caching library.

For example http://www.phpfastcache.com/

```
// In your config file
include("phpfastcache/phpfastcache.php");
phpFastCache::setup("storage","auto");

// phpFastCache support "apc", "memcache", "memcached", "wincache" ,"files", "sqlite" and "xcache"
// You don't need to change your code when you change your caching system. Or simple keep it auto
$cache = phpFastCache();

// In your Class, Functions, PHP Pages
// try to get from Cache first. product_page = YOUR Identity Keyword
$results = $cache->get("cache_instagram");

if($results == null) {
    $clientid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/kittens/media/recent?client_id=".$clientid;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $results = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    // set products in to cache in 600 seconds = 10 minutes
    $cache->set("cache_instagram", $results,600);
}

// Output Your Contents $products HERE
// Re-written first example from page for purpouse of your script.
```

For Laravel built-in caching

```
// http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache

if (Cache::has('cache_instagram')) {
    $results = Cache::get('cache_instagram');

} else {
    $clientid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/kittens/media/recent?client_id=".$clientid;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $results = curl_exec($curl);

    Cache::put('cache_instagram', $results, 60); // 1 hour

}

$results = json_decode($results);
```

Comment: It works with PHP. Its standalone library. Let me edit answer

Comment: Added information about built-in laravel caching.
However, you did not write in your question you were using laravel

Comment: Raw Curl is the right solution. Because guzzle was giving SSL error randomly on my case (Laravel 5.4).