# Using WordPress to cache Instagram feed

Tags: php, wordpress, instagram

I have an Instagram feed on my website:

```
$instagram_user_id = 'MY USER ID';
$instagram_access_token = 'MY ACCESS TOKEN';

<?php

function fetchData($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$instagram_user_id/media/recent/?access_token=$instagram_access_token&count=9");
$result = json_decode($result); ?>

<?php foreach ($result->data as $insta) { 

echo '<a target="blank" href="'.$insta->link.'">';

$img = $insta->images->low_resolution->url;
?>

<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $img; ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;"></div></a>

<?php } ?>
```

This is working well but I recently discovered that Instagram limits to 200 requests per hour.

My question is - can I cache these results?

I have tried using `set_transient` but with no luck.

Edit: this is how I am trying to use transient:

```
<?php

$cached_result = get_transient('transient');

//if transient is not set
if(empty($cached_result)) { 

function fetchData($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$instagram_user_id/media/recent/?access_token=$instagram_access_token&count=9");
$result = json_decode($result);

//set the transient
set_transient('transient', $cached_result, 60*60*6);

}
//tell me if transient is set
if(!empty($cached_result)) {

echo 'full';

} 

?>
```

But it doesn't seem the transient is set, it's calling each time.

Comment: Yes, you can, however I am not sure if that is against their terms and conditions. This answer might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144579/cache-instagram-api-request

Comment: Do not just tell us that you tried something “with no luck” - _show us_ what you tried.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73654/cache-remote-http-request-with-transients-api has a pretty extensive explanation on how to work with transients to cache data from an external API call.

Comment: @CBroe edited with my attempt to use transient. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ULook at this code you are using.

```php
set_transient('transient', $cached_result, 60*60*6);
```

First you have to hold the data in the variable cached_result then set it.
The first line of code you are calling get_transient but there is no value on the transient key just because the value is not set.

Thanks!!